# JSHint "Bad or unnecessary escaping." Do double slashes beginning/end matter?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm storing some RegExps in an Object as strings, but getting the above error message.

I believe this is because they aren't prefixed with / or suffixed with / - as I'm running them into a new RegExp() constructor, as the script allows users to define RegExps, so I want them all to be dynamic.

```
var patterns = {
    email: '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$',
    url: '[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)',
    number: '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$',
    empty: '^\\s*$'
};
```

There's the above strings.

To fix them I can do this and / / them:

```
var patterns = {
    email: '/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/',
    url: '/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/',
    number: '/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$',
    empty: '/^\\s*$/'
};
```

But when called via `new RegExp()` surely they'll do this (for example):

```
var reg = new RegExp(patterns.empty);
/**
 * reg = //^\\s*$//
 */
```

With double slashes. My question as a bit of a RegExp beginner, is do these double slashes matter? Can it be fixed another way. JSHint is complaining because it's not a "real" RegExp.

I can also remove them from strings and store as true RegExps, but again I need them to be dynamic. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's considerably easier to use native regular expression literals if you don't have dynamic regular expressions (ones that need runtime values in order to be constructed).

Comment: @jfriend00 Please read: "I can also remove them from strings and store as true RegExps, but again I need them to be dynamic". Again, the same question regarding double backslashes would apply.

Comment: @Pointy - what if I'm grabbing the regexp from `data-regexp="[A-Za-z]{1}"` for example. That needs constructing or it's just a string?

Comment: If you're stuck with strings, then you're stuck with double escaping.  Regex declarations as strings are just messy.  I don't know what magic bean you're expecting us to offer you here.  If you want a string with `"\s"` in it, then you have to declare `"\\s"`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah - but do they matter or have any negative effects, or will they work like usual? :)

Comment: When you declare `"\\s"`, you end up with a javascript string that has `"\s"` in it.  No side effects - just messy to write and harder to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the backslash character (`\`) is used both for escaping special characters in string literals (e.g. `\n` is interpreted as a single newline character, and `\\` as a single backslash character), and it's used in escaping special characters in regular expressions.

So when a string literal is used for a regexp, and you need the regexp to see `\`, you need to escape the backslash and include `\\` in the string literal. Specifically, in `email` you need `\\.` rather than `\.`. E.g.

```
email: '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$'
```

Alternatively, you could put the regular expressions in `/.../` rather than `'...'` (or `'/.../'`). Then string literal escaping doesn't apply, and you don't need to double the slashes. E.g.

```
email: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

In the latter case, you also don't need `new RegExp(patterns.email)`, since `patterns.email` is already a RegExp object.